# Escaping single quotes JSON

Tags: python, json

I am using the json module to convert a series of dictionaries to json but I am not sure why when dumping to json the strings that contain a single quote (e.g: My father's car) are escaped to (My father\'s car). When I check in an online validator it saying that the format is wrong. Why dumps escape them when it is not correct?

I tried to replace the strings using replace but it does not act of them. Would that be a valid solution? Why is not working the following snipped

```
formatted_json = json.dumps(OrderedDict([("nodes", json_graph['nodes']), ("links", json_graph['links'])])).replace('\'',"'")
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a [mcve]. Because json is _not_ escaping simple quotes here (since quoting is done with double quotes)

Comment: `'\''` and `"'"` both spell the *exact same string value*. You replaced single quotes with single quotes. You are probably looking a the `repr()` output for a string that contains both single and double quotes, so Python gives you a *string literal value* that can be copied and pasted to reproduce that value. and in a string literal with both `"` and `'` characters, you have to escape one or the other for this to work. That doesn't mean that the actual value has escapes in them..

Answer (score 9):

You probably see the value representation from python interpreter. If you print the value or store it in a file, you'll see the correct behaviour.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps("a'b")
'"a\'b"'
>>> print json.dumps("a'b")
"a'b"
```

Comment: recently ran into this issue.  the problem i see is when you return json.dumps to a flask backend and render using the flask placeholder tags, those escape characters are written as part of the string that is embedded in the page.